# unsigned long long int constant value vs. multiplicative value

Tags: c

I tried the below, and it seems that 'test' results in wrong value.   2500*2500*2500 == 15625000000, why the below operations result in different outcome?

```
unsigned long long int test = 2500*2500*2500;
fprintf(stderr, "*************** test = %lld, %llu\n", test, test);
unsigned long long int test2 = 15625000000;
fprintf(stderr, "*************** test2 = %lld, %llu\n", test2, test2);
```

Result:

```
*************** test = -1554869184, 18446744072154682432
*************** test2 = 15625000000, 15625000000
```

Comment: maybe because it is being computed at runtime and your 32 bit computer overflows because it can't work with 64 bit values for some reason?

Comment: Try adding `ULL` to at least one of the `2500` constants in your expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2500 * 2500 * 2500` is never promoted past `int`, so the signed overflow that occurs (which is, by the way, UB) stops the correct calculation from being performed.

To allow it, you must tell the compiler that your literals are of a particular type. There are two ways to do this:

1. **By casting**—casting a literal is generally handled at compile-time and has no runtime overhead:

   ```
   unsigned long long int test = (unsigned long long int)2500 * (unsigned long long int)2500 * (unsigned long long int)2500;
   ```

   Note that the cast is performed on the multiplicands individually. If the result of the operation were cast (e.g. `(unsigned long long int)(2500 * 2500 * 2500)`) then the cast would be too late to preserve the data.
2. **By suffixing**:

   ```
   unsigned long long int test = 2500ULL * 2500ULL * 2500ULL;
   ```

   This is exactly as efficient at runtime as casting of literals is, but depending on usage may be easier or harder to read. Suffixing must be applied directly to a literal (it cannot be applied to the result of an operation, so  `(2500 * 2500 * 2500)ULL` is illegal.)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you only need to suffix the first constant, because if one operand is of type `unsigned long long` then the other operand will be promoted.

Answer (score 2):

`2500*2500*2500` is not an unsigned long long just because you're copying it to an unsigned long long. The multiplications are done with `int`s, so the result of the multiplication is an `int`. By the time the upgrade to `unsigned long long` happens, it's too late. Use `2500ULL`.